# change permission of file transferred into linux box from windows

Tags: windows, linux, batch-file, putty

I  am remotely transfering the files into linux box from windows via batch script and inside batch script I am  using putty cmd and executing it through plink.exe
The problem, I  am facing is when it actually get transferred into linux box it failed to execute as it does not contain executable file permissions.

My question is how will I change file permission to something 755or 777 remotely?

Thanks and reagrds,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as localy:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/file
```

You can run this command using `plink` also